# w1 -= learning_rate * grad_w1 : why is this not available in python 3.7 jupyterLab?

Tags: python

---

During running python on jupyterLab, I met this  error messages.
This makes me confused because it was not a syntax error basically.
I would appreciate in advance someone who let me know why or what that message means.

```
# Update weights
w1 -= learning_rate * grad_w1
w2 -= learning_rate * grad_w2
```

After all, changed those like this, I got the results.

```
# Update weights
w1 = w1 - learning_rate * grad_w1
w2 = w2 - learning_rate * grad_w2
```

[image: Error message captured]

Comment: put the error in the question

Comment: How are `learning_rate`, `grad_w1` and `grad_w2` defined ?

Comment: What type is `w1`? The problem appears to be with the definition of its `__isub__` method.